TypeError from using FINCH() imported from finch-clust library for clustering
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from finch import FINCH

n_samples = 5000
n_clusters = 5
random_state = 42

X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples, centers=n_clusters, random_state=random_state)

fin = FINCH()
fin.fit(X)

print(fin.partitions)

I want to print the partitions and number of clusters in each partition from the FINCH algorithm. However, I keep getting this error:
TypeError: FINCH() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Optional parameters for the FINCH class are:
metric (default='euclidean'): The used distance metric
n_jobs (default=1): The number of processes to start -1 means use all processors
I don't know why a class call needs a 'data' value.
Trying this piece of sample code from this GitHub https://github.com/eren-ck/finch/blob/main/demo/demo.ipynb

There're two finch libraries that look similar:
finchpy and finch-clust
It looks like you've installed finch-clust that has required data argument. But using code for finchpy.
Try:
pip uninstall finch-clust
pip install finchpy

to use finchpy.
Or refer finch-clust usage documentation and update your code.

Absolute legend.
Thanks
